# Reset Root Password on Solaris 10

Tags: solaris

So, I have an interesting problem. The root password on one of our Sun x4500 machines was changed and never communicated. Now, nobody knows what it is. I have physical access to the machine, but no Solaris installation disc. Is there any way to reset the password, this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any linux/bsd distribution which can mount your drive filesystem should have the same capability.

A [FreeBSD liveCD](http://livecd.sourceforge.net/download.php) would likely be your best candidate in the absence of the Solaris media. (BSDs support UFS.)

Good luck!

Comment: Another alternative is the OpenIndiana LiveCD. Since it's an Illumos (Solaris) kernel it also has ZFS/UFS support just like FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [step-by-step guide](http://www.stsolutions.com/newsletter/ask_al_issue04.html) to resetting the root password on Solaris 10, it requires you have the Solaris 10 installation disc, and physical access to the machine though.

Comment: I have physical access to the machine, but no Solaris disc. Know any other way?

Comment: Maybe download a Solaris 10 disc and burn it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the OpenSolaris Live CD: http://www.opensolaris.com/

Boot the Live CD and mount your partition...then clear out the password in the shadow file.

This will work if you're using UFS or ZFS root.

Answer (score 0):

The one time I've had to do this without physical or console access, I managed to find a privilege escalation exploit that applied to my OS and patchlevel and got a root shell that way.  Might be a long-shot, but otherwise I'd take a look at http://www.sysresccd.org/, since it appears to support ufs.

Comment: Talk about doing it the hard way!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can boot selecting the single user mode in GRUB and then proceding to reset the root password.

Comment: Not in Solaris - single user mode still requires you to enter the root password before allowing root privileges.